# Unable to Connect via Ethernet and Wireless to the Same Network

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I have an oldish Lenovo Ideapad running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that I want to be able to use in my home LAN by both ethernet and WiFi - the idea being to connect via ethernet during times when 802.11 just isn't up to the job. The WiFi link is stable and has been stable for years, however I am having issues with the hardline connection - with or without the wifi enabled. I've tried rolling back to the r8168 as some have indicated that is usually the path to resolve issues with this particular network card, but had no luck.

ifconfig:

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether c8:5b:76:76:eb:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 702  bytes 107366 (107.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 3 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 34  base 0x9000
```

lshw for the relevant device:

```
       description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: c8:5b:76:76:eb:be
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:34 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:f0a04000-f0a04fff memory:f0a00000-f0a03fff
```

dmesg shows a pattern of the link on enp2s0 coming up and then going back down about a second later, pretty consistently, throughout the entire time the machine is powered up with a line connected in that port. The cable is known-good, as is the switch itself (which is known good all the way out to the internet for two other machines that are using it at the moment).

I'm sort of at a loss of where to dig deeper here. I've tried getting ethtool to set autonegotiation to false (another troubleshooting step), but no luck.

Comment: You can't be connected both ways without setting some routing for that.

Comment: That's not a surprise, and I've thought of that. However, the ethernet link still refuses to activate. Editing my question for clarity.

Comment: link=no indicates a possible cable problem, or switch problem. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Have you power-cycled the switch by unplugging from AC power for 15 seconds? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema - I have, and I've also been trying different cables and ports on the switch. Whenever I unplug the cable and reconnect it, I get the link light on the switch for a second or so, which goes out. This is reflected in dmesg - I can't see any link lights on the NIC itself so I'm not sure what's happening there.

With the same cable I can keep the link light on under certain conditions, but none of those old hacks seem to still work.

Comment: Did you reboot the switch? What happens if you run the cable directly to the router/modem? It could be an auto-negotiation problem, but you've tried that, correct?

Comment: @heynnema I get the same behavior if I plug into the router, though I have to admit I haven't tried the modem itself - wouldn't be a practical solution to the problem due to the location of the modem. Switch is rebooted.

I did try poking at the autoneg setting in ethtool, in the manner of:
`sudo ethtool -s $interface speed 100 duplex full autoneg off`. This sometimes causes the link to stay up, but dhclient just hangs after that (and maybe that's to be expected with autoneg off, I'm not really sure.)

Comment: Last ditch idea... boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB 20.04 and see if the ethernet works. Some of the older kernels had problems with these cards.

Comment: @heynnema finally got around to trying that, and no love. I have to assume it's the NIC itself that's dead at this point.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact model Lenovo Ideapad that you have.

Comment: @heynnema: your command responds `1LCN32WW`. I've also booted into windows with no improvement, so I really do suspect the card itself is at fault here. This is an ideapad 310-15ABR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lenovo Ideapad 310-15ABR

You have an old BIOS, 1LCN32WW.

There's a newer BIOS available, 1LCN50WW, and can be downloaded from [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds113320).

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Note**: Some recent kernels have had a problem with r8168 cards, so you should try booting to a Ubuntu Live 20.04 DVD/USB to check if the problem is resolved.

Comment: In my (particular) instance this did not actually resolve the issue as there is a hardware problem.

Howwwwwwwever, I can confirm based on past experiences with repairing Lenovo machines that a BIOS update often is the solution to apparent hardware failures.

Comment: @PatchSavage87 What hardware problem? Did you update the BIOS?

Comment: @PatchSavage87 I've seen bad kernels cause what appears to be a defective r8168 hardware problem. Did the 20.04 Live DVD/USB make the card work?

Comment: no, nor did the BIOS update.

Upon physical inspection of the board I noticed what looks to be a broken trace in the near neighbourhood of the RJ45 connector. I'm not NEARLY brave enough to attempt to repair that so I'm just going to eat the loss and either upgrade the whole machine or obtain an adapter.

Comment: @PatchSavage87 If it **IS** a broken trace, any repair tech can easily fix that for you.